# When/why should I start using a database?

Tags: database, refactoring

I'm currently in the process of evaluating the design, and possible reimplementation of an in-house app our engineers use.

Although the application handles large amounts of data. Only two sets of values (floats) are saved along with a simple name and description of the data. In my opinion the current application is in overkill territory using a normalized access database to store what evaluates to 7 fields of strings and floats.

At what point do you start looking at transitioning from a flat file or serialized XML to a relational database or vice versa?

Comment: strange; i cant mark this as community wiki...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would recommend using a lightweight database like SQLite which reduces a lot of the overhead of using a database.

http://sqlite.org

Comment: With a nice ORM abstracting the DB so he can transition to something bigger in the future if need be. Pays to design defensively.

Comment: "abstracting the db", why are kids these days so scared of SQL?

Comment: scared? The "standard" is inconsistent, every DB software has its own flavour of SQL, its escaping is a royal pain (especially when creating stored procedures and functions), you need to encapsulate and escape data very carefully to avoid SQL injection... but hey, that's nothing to be scared of!  - It is just a reason to avoid SQL altogether if possible.

Comment: Using SQLite doesn't necessarily mean you have to use SQLite-specific SQL.  We don't have any SQLite specific SQL in our application.  The advantage though is SQLite requires no installation, no maintenance, and is really lightweight.

Answer (score 4):

Databases can have huge advantages over flat files, even if you only have a single table with a few values.

They can dramatically improve query speed if you have a large amount of data - if you only need to find one value via a key, pulling this from a DB with an index prevents you from having to parse the entire file and search.

Comment: Don't forget data integrity issues too. DBs take care of dealing with making sure the data actually gets written to disk.

Answer (score 3):

You should use the db right away because of a key word: engineer **s** (the plural is key)

Trying to recreate the [ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) principles of any worthwhile RDBMS, even for a small amount of data even for a few users, will clobber your chances for success. You also won't have backups, custom querying and a dozen of other abilities that an RDBMS provides "out of the box."

Answer (score 3):

Databases are going to be better equipped to query the data. If you mean 7 values - use a flat file. If you mean 7 fields, where there could be hundreds or thousands of records (each containing 7 fields), then use a database - particularly if you need to sort or otherwise query those records.

Answer (score 2):

I start when I have to maintain a large set of *related* data entities.

When you a start having many-to-many or many-to-one type relationships within your data, it is time to think about using a relational database to maintain relational integrity.