# How to make this file upload secure?

Tags: php, security

I wrote this piece of PHP to enable simple PHP File-Uploading with base64-strings.

Back then, it was just supposed to work (and it does). But now I want to beef it up to make this actually secure against malicious intents.

I use this script for an app of mine (file uploads):

```
if(isset($_GET["upload"]))
{
    $contents = $_POST["contents"];

    $file = fopen("filename.wav", "w");
    $input = base64_decode($contents);
    fwrite($file, $input);
    fclose($file);
}
```

Comment: What's insecure about it? You should use `$_FILES` obviously, but there's nothing 'wrong' with this code.

Comment: Why are you checking a `GET` variable for a `POST` request? That's highly inconsistent. The request is either POST or GET. While you can do what you're doing, I'd recommend to stick to only one method.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can input written to a file be maliciously tampered?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14555392/can-input-written-to-a-file-be-maliciously-tampered)

Answer (score -1):

You can check if it is an uploaded file via HTTP using `is_uploaded_file`: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_is_uploaded_file.asp

```
<?php
$file = "test.txt";
if(is_uploaded_file($file))
  {
  echo ("$file is uploaded via HTTP POST");
  }
else
  {
  echo ("$file is not uploaded via HTTP POST");
  }
?>
```